# How to make dynamically changing text in a button in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

When user taps "download" button i need to change the title of a button to 
"loading..." but the number of dots must dynamically change from 1 to 3. How can i make it for certain amount of time(5-10 sec) ? Or do i just need to setTitle multiple times ?

```
button.setTitle("loading.", forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
button.setTitle("loading.", forState: .Normal)
button.setTitle("loading..", forState: .Normal)
button.setTitle("loading...", forState: .Normal)
```

whenever you want to change the number of dots.
Call one of the above after a delay or whenever you need to update the button.

**EDIT:** To prevent your button's title from blinking (as pointed out by [teamnorge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3317354/teamnorge)) use:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    button.setTitle("loading...", forState: .Normal)
}
```

Comment: This may produce a blinking animation, I would suggest replacing UIButton with UILabel before changing its title.

Comment: I addressed that issue in my edit, without the need of an UILabel

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setTitle("my text here", forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func renameClassButton(sender: AnyObject) {
     classTopButton.text = "\(classTopTextField)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can d it this way:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loading: UIButton!

    //Create an array for your button name
    let buttonNameArray = ["loading.","loading..","loading..."]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func loadingButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        //Set delay time for changing name
        var delayTime = 1.0

        for name in buttonNameArray {

            self.delay(delayTime++){
                self.loading.setTitle(name, forState: .Normal)
            }
        } 
    }

    //Function for delay
    func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))),dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }
}
```

And your result will be:

[image]

Hope this will help.